# AbstractMethodError when moving a class from one module to another in a gradle groovy project

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm getting this exception at runtime, I've replaced the actual class name with `com.foo.Bar`

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.foo.Bar does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
```

This is a groovy project, and I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with Gradle. As I get this exception when I moved a class from one module to another. There is the only change I made, and it worked before when it was in the other module, but in the class path as `implementation project(":foobar")`.

I have a structure in my project like:

```
/build.gradle
/app/build.gradle
/util/build.gradle
```

And I moved the class from `util` to `app`. These `build.gradle` files both have the same `groovy` version in their classpath with the same `groovy` plugin.

I am stumped.

**Edit**
After doing some digging I thought I might check what the difference is between the compiler produces and they differ significantly!!

The working version has more annotations:

```java
  @Generated
  public Object call(Object args) {
      return this.doCall(args);
  }

  @Generated
  public Object call() {
      return this.doCall((Object)null);
  }
```

Also has this stuff at the bottom:

Working

```
    @Generated
    @Internal
    @Transient
    public MetaClass getMetaClass() {
        MetaClass var10000 = this.metaClass;
        if (var10000 != null) {
            return var10000;
        } else {
            this.metaClass = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
            return this.metaClass;
        }
    }

    @Generated
    @Internal
    public void setMetaClass(MetaClass var1) {
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you push a cut down example to github with instructions on how to see the failure you're seeing?

Comment: I've posted an answer. Was the spring dependency plugin interfering with my dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did figure out what the issue was for anyone else having this problem. To ensure all my modules had the same version of groovy, in `/build.gradle` I had:

```
subprojects {
  dependencies {
    constraints {
      implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:someVersion"
   }
 }
}
```

But meanwhile I was using `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin. This plugin specified some other version behavior of groovy, which ended up meaning that `app` and `util` had different groovy settings.

The fix was just figuring out what version of groovy was actually being used with the version of the Spring Plugins I was using. I did this by generating a new project with [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and running `gradle dependencies`. And then setting `someVersion` to this value. In my case this was `3.0.12`.